# Aligning Text within Legend with Example Code

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am wanting to get the cleanest look using this code chunk which overlays my plot in R

```
legend(130, 0.0150, legend = c(paste0("Large diameter  ", format(center, digits=6)),
                            paste0("Minimum            ", format(min2, digits=6))),
       bty = "n")
```

Notice the large white spaces. But this achieves the effect I want

But I know there's a better way to do this! I additionally want to add more descriptive statistics to the plot and this has to be a very inefficient way of doing it. So, what's the best way to align the text and numbers? Any way to beautify to this further? Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just print two legends side by side.

***Example***

*Example plot:*

```
curve(cos(x)/100, xlim=c(0, 250), ylim=c(0, .02), col="blue")
center <- 135.873; min2 <- 86.3301  # values
```

*Legend:*

```
legend(130, 0.0150, legend=c("Large diameter", "Minimum"), bty="n")
legend(200, 0.0150, legend=c(format(center, digits=6), 
                             format(min2, digits=6)), bty="n")
```

[image]

Comment: nice. and you can calculate the x-coordinate of the second legend more precisely with `m <- strwidth(paste(c("Large diameter", "Minimum"), ''))` then `legend(130 + max(m), ...)`

Comment: excellent addition @rawr. this approach keeps the process self contained